# Conditional Email Notification on DAG Failure

Tags: airflow

I have a Airflow **1.10** DAG with the following sequence of operators -

```
PythonOperator1 --> S3KeySensor --> PythonOperator2 --> PythonOperator3
```

My requirement is to send email notification if -

- S3KeySensor fails (timeout occurs waiting for file with `soft_fail=True` i.e. skipped)
- PythonOperator2 or PythonOperator3 fails
- No need to send email if DAG completes successfully

Can anyone please help how to implement this **conditional** logic with the `EmailOperator`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `on_failure_callback` config option for every Airflow task. It's value is supposed to be a python callable. So you'd need to configure your tasks (S3KeySensor, PythonOperator based) like that:

```
def send_email(context=None):
    from airflow.operators.email import EmailOperator

    email_alert = EmailOperator(...)

    slack_alert.execute(context)

with DAG(...) as dag:
    task_a = S3KeySensor(on_failure_callback=send_email, ...)
    task_b = PythonOperator(on_failure_callback=send_email, ...)

    task_a > task_b
```

More info on callbacks:

- https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.2.1/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html

Remember that Airflow 1.* is deprecated already so it's recommended to use Airflow 2+.

Comment: thanks @mrp1nk, will this work even if the S3KeySensor times out waiting for the file to arrive (`soft_fail=True`), and the downstream operators will be marked as "`Skipped`" ?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the use case - if soft_fail is True then after timeout on_failure_callback will be run. I recommend good article on sensors: https://marclamberti.com/blog/airflow-sensors/